# Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

the Gradle is continuously running saying "waiting for device to come online"
and after some time giving error msg "Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online"

Answer (score 1):

following solutions worked for me

- delete data of emulator, It will run fine
- Restart your emulator using the power button
- Add a new emulator, It will run fine

Comment: wipe out data worked